# Does IDA Pro's Freeware version have a command line interface?

Tags: ida

Does anybody know if IDA's FreeWare version 7.0 has the Command Line Interface option?

I currently have IDA FreeWare 7.0 and I only see one .exe file which is ida64.exe. But according to HexRay's command line switches for IDA Pro, there is supposed to be an .exe for command line interface. I'm not sure if it's just because I am using the free version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what you mean by "Command Line Interface".

You can pass a filename to the ida64 executable on command line and it will be opened. Some of the switches (like `-A`, `-T`, `-L`) also work, but for example `-B` and `-S` are disabled.

If you want the text-mode `idat` executable, you need the full version (Pro or Starter).